# sfc /scannow win 2003 R2

Tags: rdp, windows-server-2003-r2, mstsc

I have win 2003 r2 when i'm trying to launch sfc /scannow an utility runs but closes in a couple of minutes. In event journal there are no errors. chkdsk shows no errors. I establish connection to this server via rdp with /admin /console keys.

Additionally on this server an utility mstsc has stopped to work, launch of this utility does nothing. (That's why i have encountered the problem with sfc)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try running it in safe mode. can you let us know if that helps? its possible that something in the full boot is crashing it, especially if your OS is corrupt

Comment: Thanks. In the safe mode i got that sfc cannot be run due to inaccessibility of rpc server. I tried to start Remote Procedure Call (RPC) Locator service and got a notification that it's impossible to run this service in safe mode.

Comment: There is a workaround for that somewhere, but I dont know it personally. Honestly, I have always considered sfc /scannow to be the "I dont know the problem, maybe Ill get lucky fix". It may be  best to let us know why you have to run this command and we can try to help you that way

Comment: briefly i want to make mstsc utility works. Currently it just shows nothing when i'm trying to start it.

Answer (score 0):

Boot the system with server 2003 CD and repair your existing Windows installation.   This method does not delete any configuration and applications.

https://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/02/16/effectively-repairing-windows-2003-server/